# Is there any standard for the following type of authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, openid

We are partner to another company. We developed an asp.net site with membership as the provider. Our partner company requests the following. The users would log in to their site through their UI. Once the user is logged in, there is a link to our site. They want to bypass our login screen and let the users get into our site after they authenticate the user. Is there any standard for this? I checked openid, but it didn't seem like a quite fit. As far as I understood, in openid, there needs to be a link in our login page saying "Login using Company X". Then when the user clicks that the user is taken to Company X login page. Once the user is authenticated is redirected to the link we provided and the user is authenticated. Our partner company doesn't want the user to come to our login page. I still want to use everything that membership provides such as roles.

Comment: sure. the link on their site would be basically `http://yoursite.com/user_auto_login.php?id=long_ugly_encrypted_string_that_proves_the_user_logged_into_the_partner_site_first`. you capture that string. decrypt it, validate the data, then auto-login the user.

Comment: Is what you describe OpenID?

Comment: at a very basic level

Comment: Is there a need for a server that creates tokens for that? For example the id you mentioned is created on the token server and they call the site. Then I retrieve the id and make a call to token server to validate the token?

Comment: the partner site would be the token server, in this case.

Comment: So this token should somehow tell me who the user is, right?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Claim Based Authentication.

Basically, you can redirect a user to your Partner Site. The user logins at their site, and then your Partner issues security token.

[image]

You can download the book - [A Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control, Second Edition - Book Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=28362)

**Source:** about slide is from [PluralSight - Identity and Access Control in ASP.NET 4.5](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/iac-aspnet)

Comment: What I described is different. Partner site offers many different services and the one we developed is one of them. People don't type our url. They go to Partner site and login. Then they can click a link to our web site. From then our site should treat them as logged in and let them use the site.

Comment: Basically, it is same principal *(2nd part of step 1 in the picture)*. When a use click a links to your site, your partner should forward the credential to your site. For example, Basic Authentication (credential is in header) or Token (your partner becomes token issuer)